# Why I need to press twice times to submit my form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, forms

I want to submit my login form, but I need to press twice times to accomplish login form, I don't know what happen.
I'm using styled components, this Button Form is an **input** tag
Also I'm using **firebase-hooks**
I just want to click one time and submit

Here my code

```
export default function LoginForm() {
  // submit
  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    if (user) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        history.push(`${ROUTES.HOME}`);
      }, 1000);
    }
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <FormContainer onSubmit={(e) => handleLogin(e)}>
      <LogoContainer>
        <img
          src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/auth-c068d.appspot.com/o/instagram%2Finstagram-signup.png?alt=media&token=cdafffb1-3034-474d-be96-d507b5e416c6"
          alt="instagram-logo"
        />
      </LogoContainer>

      <input
        id="email"
        type="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Email"
        required
      />
      <input
        id="password"
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Password"
        required
      />
      <ButtonForm type="submit" name="btn-login" value="Log In" />
      <p>
        Don't have an account? <Link to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>
      </p>
      {error && <Error errorMessage={error.message} />}
    </FormContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you put a console.log at the top of `handleLogin` does it print after just the first submit? If so it probably has something to do with the code in that function after the preventDefault

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you will need to use a useEffect hook here. Your handleLogin function only runs **once** on each click. The first time you submit, user is undefined as expected. It works when you click it the second time because user is truthy.

**Try removing this from the handleLogin function.**

```
if (user) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    history.push(`${ROUTES.HOME}`);
  }, 1000);
}
```

**Then add a useEffect hook.**

```
useEffect(() => {     
if (user) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    history.push(`${ROUTES.HOME}`);
  }, 1000);
}}, [user])
```

This effect will run on component mount, **and** after each time your `user` state is changed. (This is assuming your using react state for user, as I can't see where `user` is coming from)

Answer (score 0):

change the type of button from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and handle click using `onCkick={() => clickHandler()}`